# Using a variable as a function name that could be multiple levels deep

Tags: javascript

I have had a look around the site and seem to have come across some solutions, but none seem to work. So here's the problem.

I have the following Javascript:

```js
THEOBJECT = {
  init: function() {
    this.tools.init();
  }
};

THEOBJECT.tools = {
  active: false,
  init: function() {
    // active variable updated elsewhere/loading
    if (!this.active) {
      THEOBJECT.utils.timeout('tools.init', 100);
    }
    // is active so continue   
  }
};

THEOBJECT.utils = {
  timeout: function(functionName, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      THEOBJECT[functionName]();
    }, time);
  }
};


THEOBJECT.init();
```

I am getting an error when running the `THEOBJECT.utils.timeout` saying:

> THEOBJECT[functionName] is not a function

I'm trying to run `THEOBJECT.tools.init()`

I'm assuming this is because it's not a direct function of the THEOBJECT object is there a way around this or is a split() the best way to go?

Comment: Yes, if for some reason you have to use strings instead of code then parse their structure (i.e. `split`) and evaluate them to what you need.

Comment: `THEOBJECT[functionName]();` is evaluating to `THEOBJECT["tools.init"]();`, and `THEOBJECT` doesn't have a property named `tools.init`. While not the best, you can do `eval("THEOBJECT." + functionName + "()")` but creating a recursive function to check on the object would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I figured that a recursive function would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is other option to do it using `lodash.js`. Please see the updated snippet.

Or go with conventional approch mentioned below

You are trying to access a property in wrong way

you are doing `THEOBJECT[tools.init]` which incorrect. It should be like `THEOBEJECT[tools][init]`

```js
THEOBJECT = {
  init: function() {
    this.tools.init();
  }
};

THEOBJECT.tools = {
  active: false,
  init: function() {
    // active variable updated elsewhere/loading
    if (!this.active) {
      THEOBJECT.utils.timeout('tools.init', 100);
    }
    console.log("active")
    // is active so continue   
  }
};

THEOBJECT.utils = {
  timeout: function(functionName, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
     _.get(THEOBJECT,functionName);
    }, time);
  }
};


THEOBJECT.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I was aware it wasn't being passed correctly and therefore a split would be the best way to go. The comments basically answered my question and your code does also answer it, however it wouldn't work if say I passed a name of "tools.popup.init" as there would be too many elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can also go with a simple reduce and make it a one-liner:

```
functionName.split('.').reduce((acc,curr) => return acc[curr], THEOBJECT)();
```

---

within your code:

```js
THEOBJECT = {
  init: function() {
    this.tools.init();
  }
};

THEOBJECT.tools = {
  active: false,
  init: function() {
    // active variable updated elsewhere/loading
    if (!this.active) {
      THEOBJECT.utils.timeout('tools.init', 100);
    }
    // is active so continue   
  }
};

THEOBJECT.utils = {
  timeout: function(functionName, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      functionName.split('.').reduce((acc,curr) => acc[curr],THEOBJECT)();
    }, time);
  }
};


THEOBJECT.init();
```